# how to generate the xml from oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I have two tables as below

**Table students**

```
PersonID     firstName 
1            John
2            Mike
```

Table Marks

```
mark_id     person_id   subject   marks
1           1           English    50
2           1           Maths      75
```

the below query give the xml as below

```
select XMLElement(      "Students" ,
              (select XMLAgg( XMLElement("Student" ,                      
                             XmlElement( "Student_id","id")  ,
                             XmlElement(  "First_Name","firstname")  
                             ))
                             FROM students  )
                             )
                               AS "RESULT" 
From dual

<Students>
<Student>
<Student_id>1</Student_id>
<First_Name>John</First_Name>
</Student>
<Student>
<Student_id>2</Student_id>
<First_Name>Mike</First_Name>
</Student>
<Students>
```

Now I need to do a left join the table `students` with `Marks`
and create a xml like below

```
<Students>
    <Student>
    <Student_id>1</Student_id>
    <First_Name>John</First_Name>
    <Marks>
     <subject>English</subject>
     <mark>50</mark>
     <subject>Maths</subject>
     <mark>75</mark>
    </Marks>
    </Student>
    <Student>
    <Student_id>2</Student_id>
    <First_Name>Mike</First_Name>
    <Marks/>
    </Student>
    <Students>
```

how can i achieve if i write the select query it will return two rows for the first student since it has 2 rows to join in the second mark table.

Comment: Depends on what the requirements are. If there are multiple marks and there should only be one row per student, you can use a `group by` clause.

Comment: @AluanHaddad there can be multiple subject and marks for students and some times no marks. So I am using left join

Comment: `Students as Student left join Marks as Mark on .... group by ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select XMLElement(
         "Students" ,
         XMLAgg(
           XMLElement(
             "Student" ,
             XMLFOREST(
               s."Student_id" AS "id",
               s."First_Name" AS "firstname"
             ),
             m.marks
           )
         )
       )
FROM   students s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT person_id,
                XMLELEMENT(
                  "Marks",
                  XMLAGG(
                    XMLFOREST(
                      "subject",
                      "marks" AS "mark"
                    )
                  )
                ) AS marks
         FROM   Marks
       ) m
       ON ( s."PersonID" = m.person_id )
```

*(Note: unless there is a specific business need, it is [not good practice to use quoted identifiers for table/column names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38328674/1509264); just use unquoted identifiers everywhere and let oracle manage the case (in)sensitivity.)*