# how to extract data from oracle table having space in column name using vba code?

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

I really need some advice on this. Please. I have a oracle table having column names with spaces. I made a code having sql select query inside, which extracts data accordingly. It works for column name without spaces like "select column from table".   i need to make work this in vba "select column name from table". What delimeters should i use. Have tried {},[],``. Please help

Comment: `"` did you try that?

Comment: Yes i tried "  " in vba code. Didn't work. marks it red.

Comment: you'll need to double them up etc, in strings as it will terminate them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes to surround an identifier with special characters:

```
SELECT "Column 1" FROM your_table
```

This will enforce [case-sensitivity on the column identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38328674/1509264); so, you need the string to be in the exact case that it was used in the database.

If you are using it in a string in VBA then you will need to [escape the quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba) (so they do not terminate your string):

```
"SELECT ""Column 1"" FROM your_table"
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoould use double quotes - the original Oracle notation.

```
create table test("Column 1" varchar2(10), column_2 number);
insert into test values('Mickey', 1);
insert into test values('Donald', 2);
insert into test values('Goofy', 3);
select * from test;
select "Spalte 1" from test;
```

For the quotes you can concat CHR(34).

```
"select " & CHR(34) & "Spalte 1" & CHR(34) & " from test"
```

Comment: fyi - "Column 1" <> "Spalte 1"